# How to download png images by url in javascript or react?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to download an image, but when i click the download button, the image is just showed, im redirected to the link and it appears. im using this function, where i pass the url as a parameter.
This function works to csv extensions, binaries too, but images its not working.. i dont know what to do =(

```
export function downloadUrl(url: string, filename?: string) {
  const element = document.createElement("a");

  element.setAttribute("href", url);

  if (filename) {
    element.setAttribute("download", filename);
  }

  element.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

<Button onClick={downloadUrl(ImageUrl)}/>
```

Comment: `downloadUrl("Url")` is meaningless. Did you mean `downloadUrl(url)` where the 'url` variable is the URL of the image? Also is this meant to be a React issue because your question and title aren't clear.

Comment: sorry, its my first question here.. In dowloadUrl(the url variable goes here). i mean, i dont know how this could be a react issue. do u have any idea? U understood the question?

Comment: The MIME type of the image file is what makes the browser decide to show it, even if you use the "download" attribute. There's not much you can do about it on the client side, as far as I know. Maybe on the server side you could make the image behave as a file.

Comment: Sorry. My point was if  you're using React as your title suggests you shouldn't be using native methods like `removeChild`. But your question isn't clear. Do you just want a vanilla JS way of loading an image, or a React way, because they're very different.

Comment: Aah, ok Andy. Sorry, its because it is a big project using typescript/react, it is isolated function probably was not the better way to do it, im jr kkkkkk. I just want resolve the problem.

Comment: @Kokodoko in this case i'll have to ask to my back-end right?

Comment: Yes, on the server you might set the MIME type and the headers of those images to generic file. Then the browser might not treat them as images any more and download them.

Comment: And you could just make it a normal link, like @Andy says, using `appendChild` and `removeChild` is not valid React code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileSaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

```
FileSaver.saveAs("https://<yourimage>", "<image-name.jpg>");
```